# How to use Liquid markup with Zendesk Trigger

Tags: liquid, zendesk

Does anyone know is it possible to mix in Liquid markup with JSON response in Zendesk triggers?
[image]

I am failing to find any good example of this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult one to confirm as each case is different. However, let's take this hypothetical example (this would be within the trigger JSON area):

> Customer created an json object file with the liquid markup code for
> inserting CC and CC email {% for cc in ticket.ccs %}  {{cc.name}}
> ({{cc.email}}) {% endfor %}

They get an error when trying to put the code into the json body. I've see the same behavior in another example when they used this JSON example in a trigger that is hitting an HTTP target with a JSON payload. When they removed the piece that attempts to run the 'for' loop, and just replaced it with "cc_names": "{{ticket.ccs}}", the error went away.

My understanding was that if they were hoping to send ticket cc information to an HTTP target, they'll likely have to work with the {{ticket.ccs}} and {{ticket.cc_names}} instead of looping through the whole {{ticket.ccs}} array, as Liquid logic can't be run here.

Hope this helps give you a better understanding!

Comment: Thanks Jonny, but in the end, it was my error. I asked the same question on Zendesk community forum, and I was suggested to put that template into email alert. I discovered that my template was not forming JSON correctly and I was able to rectify the error.

JSON parser doesn't work in "Notify Target" and it will throw errors even when query is formed properly, but Lucid queries do work with this target at least..

Comment: For anyone reading this answer - P.S. HTTP Targets are now deprecated and you can create `webhook` (s) instead.

Answer (score 0):

After posting on Zendesk community forum, I learned couple of things:

1. Liquid markup does work in "Notify target" trigger
2. Parser does not know how to parse them and it throws errors (but trigger can be saved)
3. I can use "email notification" to debug my JSON responses.

So, there was an error in my JSON, and once I rectified the template the trigger started working (well, web hook did, trigger was working from the start).

Answer (score 0):

For the JSON template to work, it is necessary not to put a comma at the end of the array.

```
{
  "comments": [
    {% for comment in ticket.comments %}
        {
            "author":"{{comment.author.name}}",
            "id":"{{comment.id}}"
        }
    {% if forloop.last == false %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}
  ],
}
```